# What's the meaning of "hot codepath" (or "hot code path")?

Tags: idioms

I read this sentence (about computer programming):

> As long as this is not in your hot codepath, the extra step should not cause issues.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn’t an English question, it’s a programming question. It’s also a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22894877/471272) whose principal essential [answer by Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22894932/471272) starts out this way:

> Compiler hot paths are code execution paths in the compiler in which most of the execution time is spent, and which are potentially executed very often.

Comment: Though "hot codepath" does not refer only to compilers, but to any software application.

Comment: I am seeking clarity about the rules, not critisizing: Why wasn't this question moved (migrated) to another stack?

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD I suppose I could have done that, but it would have required a bit of hanky-panky to close it as a dupe on the far side.

Comment: Thanks - I'll eventually figure out the intricacies of the rules and when/how to enforce them. I appreciate you responding. :0)